# Update extjs chart config on its store update

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I am going to use Extjs gauge chart in my application, I want to update some config option on its store update,
for eg. you can see code on bellow link.
[Ext JS Chart Kitchen Sink](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.4/extjs-build/examples/build/ChartsKitchenSink/#basic-gauge)

In this code I am used Temp chart, There I want to update `maximum` (which is  maximum: 250 in code, Look 3rd chart) On its store. I am able to update its store but not `maximum` config vaiable. is any solution from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem getting lots of efforts
these bellows line get solved my problem.
by using this we can change axis or series Config.

```
Ext.getCmp('chartid').axes.get("gauge").maximum =  100;
Ext.getCmp('chartid').redraw();
```